# What does "workspace id:s" do in an RDP file?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp

I am debugging an RDP connection, and in the `.rdp` file there is a flag

```
workspace id:s:my-rdp-host.example.com
```

I see this parameter included in examples in many places on the internet like [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776516/do-start-process-ignores-wait-on-rdp-process) and in [Microsoft support](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/5a60ce8d-31a8-4db2-ae4a-4fb8099def64/cannot-save-rdp-credentials-on-client-when-using-workspace-id?forum=winserverTS). But, no one ever explains what it does. It is not even listed in the [official docs for RDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files).

So, does anyone know what the `workspace id:s:` setting does in an RDP file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This value seems to appear in remote application session when mouse is over rdp icon in task bar. For example see the icon where i set: workspace id:s:test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itr0o.jpg)